# Acer Revo 3700 display issue

Tags: command-line, hdmi

Acer Revo 3700

When connected to a pc moniter i have no issues. i took the unit down to connect to my sony flat via hdmi.  when i powered on the machine it booted up, the purple screen, ubuntu logo then it goes into a black screen.  Asks for username, then password. the only option is to ctrl alt and del, which restarts and through the same cycle.
any idea what the issue maybe>

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your second screen is turned off via display settings.
**Adding a second screen.**
First, you need to open the system settings:
[image]
Then you need to open display options
[image]
For you there might be an option to turn on or off the connected screen. Also, try dragging the screen in different places around the display you have. try that.